# Убрать многократный вызов функции

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Нужно из базы выбрать точки, которые лежат в определенном радиусе от заданной точки.

Для оптимизации запроса данные вначале выбираются в прямоугольнике, который описывает нужную окружность, а потом идет проверка на принадлежность к этой окружности

```
SELECT
  cl.ID
FROM
  clusters cl
WHERE
  cl.ZOOM = 19 AND
  cl.LATITUDE BETWEEN 50.03131181 AND 50.03167152 AND
  cl.LONGITUDE BETWEEN 36.20143168 AND 36.20199166 AND
  GEO.DISTANCE_DBL(cl.LATITUDE, cl.LONGITUDE, 50.03149167, 36.20171167) <= 0.02
```

Т.к. записей не особо много, то оракл запускает полное сканирование таблицы и для каждой записи вызывает функцию `GEO.DISTANCE_DBL`. Т.е. ограничение по прямоугольнику игнорируется.

Тогда я решил разбить запрос на подзапросы. Во внутреннем подзапросе выбрать прямоугольник, а во внешнем - отобрать по окружности

```
SELECT
  sub.ID
FROM (
  SELECT
    cl.ID,
    cl.LATITUDE,
    cl.LONGITUDE
  FROM
    clusters cl
  WHERE
    cl.ZOOM = 19 AND
    cl.LATITUDE BETWEEN 50.03131181 AND 50.03167152 AND
    cl.LONGITUDE BETWEEN 36.20143168 AND 36.20199166
) sub
WHERE
  GEO.DISTANCE_DBL(sub.LATITUDE, sub.LONGITUDE, 50.03149167, 36.20171167) <= 0.02
```

Ничего не изменилось. Функция по прежнему вызывается для каждой записи. И план показывает, что никакого подзапроса нет

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |          |   264 |  6336 |    11  (19)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION LIST SINGLE|          |   264 |  6336 |    11  (19)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL   | CLUSTERS |   264 |  6336 |    11  (19)| 00:00:01 |     4 |     4 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("GEO"."DISTANCE_DBL"(TO_NUMBER("CL"."LATITUDE"),TO_NUMBER("CL"."LONGITUDE"),
              50.03149167,36.20171167)<=0.02 AND "CL"."LATITUDE">=5.0031311809999998E+001D AND 
              "CL"."LATITUDE"<=5.0031671520000003E+001D AND "CL"."LONGITUDE">=3.6201431679999999E+001D 
              AND "CL"."LONGITUDE"<=3.6201991659999997E+001D)
```

Как-то можно принудительно заставить оракл делать вначале подзапрос?

Comment: Думаю вам нужно хранить данные в геометрическом типе данных, использовать соответствующие индексы (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/creating-spatial-index.htm) и искать области по ним

Comment: @Mike Что-то я не вижу там географических координат. Только декартовы

Comment: Поддержка обязана быть. как конкретно работает я не знаю. но вот тут http://citforum.ru/database/oracle/locator/  например есть упоминания работы с разными проекциями земли. По аналогии с другими БД подозреваю что достаточно обычной точки, но с указанием проекции в которой хранить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Функция по прежнему вызывается для каждой записи. И план показывает, что никакого подзапроса нет

Как я понимаю, `cluisters.ID` штука уникальная... попробуй принудительно разнести условия так:

```
SELECT ID
FROM clusters 
WHERE
  ZOOM = 19 AND
  LATITUDE BETWEEN 50.03131181 AND 50.03167152 AND
  LONGITUDE BETWEEN 36.20143168 AND 36.20199166
GROUP BY 
  ID
HAVING
  GEO.DISTANCE_DBL(MAX(LATITUDE), MAX(LONGITUDE), 50.03149167, 36.20171167) <= 0.02
```

Comment: Красиво. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Хинты `/*+ NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION */`, `/*+ NO_UNNEST */` ни к чему не привели. А вот добавление `ROWNUM` в подзапрос убрало слияние запросов

```
SELECT
  sub.ID
FROM (
  SELECT
    cl.ID,
    cl.LATITUDE,
    cl.LONGITUDE,
    ROWNUM
  FROM
    clusters cl
  WHERE
    cl.ZOOM = 19 AND
    cl.LATITUDE BETWEEN 50.03131181 AND 50.03167152 AND
    cl.LONGITUDE BETWEEN 36.20143168 AND 36.20199166
) sub
WHERE
  GEO.DISTANCE_DBL(sub.LATITUDE, sub.LONGITUDE, 50.03149167, 36.20171167) <= 0.02
```